# automatic mongoDB query retry mechanism in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Does someone have a PHP library or can point to some well written code that allows for automatic  re-try capability for x many retry attempts with a defined delay between the re-tries for mongoDB queries if they happen to fail?  (queries like find, update, insert, remove etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is already some built in query retry mechanism in the PHP mongodb driver:

> max number of retries exhausted, couldn't send query
>
> Code: 19
>
> The driver will automatically retry "plain" queries (not commands) a
> couple of times if the first attempt failed for certain reasons. This
> is to cause fewer exceptions during replica set failover (although you
> will probably still have to deal with some) and gloss over transient
> network issues.
>
> This can also be caused by the driver not being able to reconnect at
> all to the database (if, for example, the database is unreachable).

from: https://www.php.net/class.mongocursorexception

I also believe the Doctrine ODM also supports query retries - there is some discussion of this online and you can see it in the code here:

https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Cursor.php

And here's the documentation of the call to set it up:

> setRetryQuery( boolean|integer $retryQuery ) Set the number of times
> to retry queries after an exception. Parameters $retryQuery

http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/mongodb/class-Doctrine.MongoDB.Configuration.html

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. As the day progressed I stumbled upon Doctrine as well which does allow you to re-try read operations. It seems however that any write operations are a the responsibility of the application itself to handle any potential exceptions in. It would be nice to see some future guidance from MongoDB on what is best practice when it comes to best handling write calls failures (insert, update etc).Here is an interesting video on the topic itself form the person who wrote the PHP MongoDB driver https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enkGBspn8sI